# couchbase: how to make a group by and get the desired data

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have data like

```
type  | plan_name 
918 | Plan 10   
918 | PLAN 10   
918 | PLAN10    
918 | plan 10   
918 | Plan10    
918 | Plan 11   
918 | PLAN 11   
918 | PLAN11    
918 | plan 11   
918 | Plan11    
920 | Plan 10   
920 | PLAN 10   
920 | PLAN10    
920 | plan 10   
920 | Plan10    
920 | Plan 11   
920 | PLAN 11   
920 | PLAN11    
920 | plan 11   
920 | Plan11
```

Now i want to know the ids and count where plan_name number matches.

eg: Plan10,Plan 10,PLAN10,PLAN 10,plan10,plan 10

similar to 11

How to use group by and get this

the out put will be

```
type  plan_no count
918  10      5
918  11      5
920  10      5
920  11      5
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the data. Are those IDs for each document? If so, having duplicate IDs isn't possible. Can you paste your data in JSON format?

Comment: Also, I'm a little concerned about the irregularity of the `plan_name` data. Does this example represent all the possible variations?

Comment: id is now changes to someother col name

Comment: yes there is irregularity in plan name expcept the last number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a regex can help you as long as you only have one number grouping

Okay I made a bucket "b1" and loaded your data into the default scope and collection

```
UPSERT INTO b1 (KEY,VALUE)
VALUES ( "001",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "Plan 10" } ),
VALUES ( "002",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "PLAN 10" } ),
VALUES ( "003",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "PLAN10" } ),
VALUES ( "004",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "plan 10" } ),
VALUES ( "005",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "Plan10" } ),
VALUES ( "006",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "Plan 11" } ),
VALUES ( "007",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "PLAN 11" } ),
VALUES ( "008",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "PLAN11" } ),
VALUES ( "009",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "plan 11" } ),
VALUES ( "010",  { "type": 918, "plan_name": "Plan11" } ),
VALUES ( "011",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "Plan 10" } ),
VALUES ( "012",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "PLAN 10" } ),
VALUES ( "013",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "PLAN10" } ),
VALUES ( "014",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "plan 10" } ),
VALUES ( "015",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "Plan10" } ),
VALUES ( "016",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "Plan 11" } ),
VALUES ( "017",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "PLAN 11" } ),
VALUES ( "018",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "PLAN11" } ),
VALUES ( "019",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "plan 11" } ),
VALUES ( "020",  { "type": 920, "plan_name": "Plan11" } );
```

Now try either of these queries:

```
SELECT 
type, REGEXP_MATCHES(plan_name, "[0-9]+")[0] as plan_no, count(*) as count
FROM b1 group by REGEXP_MATCHES(plan_name, "[0-9]+")[0], type
```

or

```
Select t.plan_no, t.type, count(*) as count 
FROM (
  SELECT 
  type, REGEXP_MATCHES(plan_name, "[0-9]+")[0] as plan_no 
  FROM b1 ) as t 
group by t.plan_no, type
```

In either case you should get something like

```
count   plan_no type
5       "10"    918
5       "11"    918
5       "10"    920
5       "11"    920
```

If needed you can even create your index on the regex

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT type,  plan_no, count(1) as count
FROM b1 
LET plan_no = REGEXP_MATCHES(plan_name, "[0-9]+")[0]
GROUP BY paln_no, type
```